# MDI Child Form is scaling to the wrong size

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscalemode

I have an old C# winforms project I have support for several years now. In this project there is a main form that is an mdiparent and each other form is a child that fits inside the blank area of the parent. This has never been a problem.

Now I am trying to make modifications to this app again, but I do have a newer version of Visual Studio (2015) than I used to. So there is only ONE child form in this app that is giving me trouble. If I revert all my code, open the project, build, that form will appear/scale correctly. If I revert all my code, open the project, open the UI of the form, build, it will shrink the child to a smaller area inside the parent. It only happens on this ONE form, the rest work fine.

I have tried messing with all forms of autosizing, scaling, window size settings, etc but I think its something in VS that is causing just that one form to auto scale incorrectly and I'm not sure what it is. If I look at the auto generated code and compare it to the other forms it will set AutoScaleBaseSize to (6,15) but other forms are at (5,13). If I do like I mentioned above and revert the code but do NOT open the form, the autogenerated code for that form is (5,13) like the other forms.

What is happening in Visual Studio to change this AutoScaleBaseSize property and how can I find the culprit?

Comment: [`AutoScaleBaseSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autoscalebasesize(v=vs.110).aspx) is there for backword compatibility reasons only. You should probably remove references to it. Use [`AutoScaleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`AutoScaleDimensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscaledimensions(v=vs.110).aspx). If your `AutoScaleMode` is set to `Font`, use the same font family and size for all your Forms.

Comment: There are a few size related properties that are dependent on your hardware configuration for their range of values and are updated when you open the form in Design View and make changes that cause the current in-memory design to be saved to the designer file. Close the Designer view.  Add a `Sub New` to the FormName.vb file and move all the AutoScale_XYZ property assignments for the InitializeComponent Method to the `Sub New`. This should make the form's `AutoScaleMode` mode show as `Inherit` in the property grid.  This should prevent changes in the designer causing unwanted property updates.

Comment: Sorry for `Sub New` reference, that should be the form's constructor method for C#.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried doing what TntinMn suggested but it didn't affect anything. AutoScaleMode is already set to inherit for that form, just like all the others. So I tried creating a brand new form and copying everything over and even that did not work. I did notice on the new form the FixedSingle option displays differently than the others, so there really is some upgrading VS is doing for some forms and not others. I think I'm going to need to rebuild the project with all new forms to get this to work. I was hoping that wasn't the case, but thank you for the replies!